# Как запустить exe файл на другой машине

Tags: c++, exe

Я создал программку на с++ в visual studio, скинул всю программку на другую машину в которой отсутствует visual studio, и при запуске exe файла. выдало что у меня нет MSVC110D.dll типо такого файлика.
я закинул этот файлик в папку, но чето не пошло.

Comment: Или компилируйте со статическими библиотеками (ключ командной строки `/MT`), или установите рантайм-библиотеки на второй машине (то, что называется [Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)) для соответствующей версии Visual C++.

Comment: А как компилировать со статической библиотекой?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Или компилируйте со статическими библиотеками (ключ командной строки /MT), или установите рантайм-библиотеки на второй машине (то, что называется [Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)) для соответствующей версии Visual C++.

Компиляция со статическими библиотеками в IDE: Проект - Свойства - С/С++ - Создание кода - Библиотека времени выполнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Соберите в Release, у меня сработало