# Как запустить программу C++ на другом компьютере?

Tags: c++, exe

Допустим я написал программу, которая компилируется и работает корректно. Но она работает только на моем компьютере, а я хочу чтобы ее можно было использовать на других. Как и через что можно это сделать?
Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: а что говорит при запуске на другом компьютере?

Comment: Какая операционная система, какой компилятор, какие библиотеки... Например, может быть такая программа под Win10, которая просто не сможет работать под Win7 из-за отсутствия использованных возможностей...

Comment: Не удается продолжить выполнение кода, поскольку система не обнаружила MSVCP140D.dll. Для устранения этой проблемы попробуйте переустановить программу. Это ошибка которая появилась после запуска на другом компьютере.

Comment: У меня ОС Windows 10 64-бит, у стороннего компа такая же ОС.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/641388/195342

Comment: Если интересуют библиотеки что я юзал в программе то это string, iostream, iomapip.

Comment: Свойства проекта -> C\C++ -> Создание кода -> Библиотека времени выполнения -> Многопоточная (/MT)  Это должно сработать

Comment: Попробовал, теперь программа не работает. Выдает 38 ошибок...

Answer (score 4):

Или компилируйте со статическими библиотеками (ключ командной строки /MT), или установите рантайм-библиотеки на второй машине (то, что называется [Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)) для соответствующей версии Visual C++.

Компиляция со статическими библиотеками в IDE: Проект - Свойства - С/С++ - Создание кода - Библиотека времени выполнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]