# Visual Studio C++ Зависимость Избавиться

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

С++ ето не зависимый язык на нем даже ос пишуть и все работает. Но есть одно но и ето IDE зависимость наркомания и лечение рун таймы.

А теперь серьёзно, любая моя программа которую я создавал, на чистом windows не запускается. Решений два, или установить визуал студио что для обычного пользователя изначально бредовая идея, иле установить набор библиотек их иногда подписывают как runtime visual studio и дале год выпуска визуалки на которой написана програма. Второй вариант получше но обычного пользователя тоже не обрадует благо что для игор ети рунтаймы в большинства стоят. Если не сделать первый иле второй вариант программе вечно не хватает dll файлов.

**Вопрос: как настроить визуалку так чтобы все нужные dll встраеивались в екзешник. Иле чтобы екзешник не был зависим вообще от визуалки и был скомпилирован на чистом с++. Как избавиться от етой наркомании и чем ето грозит?**

На всякий случай realase у меня включон.

Comment: Я не согласен с закрытием вопроса, в дубликате похожий вопрос но абсолютно не понятный ответ.

Comment: Гляньт это - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1226843/195342

Comment: Кстати тут есть действительно понятный ответ (Если он робочий и все как написано). Но такая операция сразу же делает код не компилируемым так как у меня как минимум lib от OpenGl привязан и програма начинает себя вести как будто lib ы не рабочие иле их нет. А мен нужно по сути избавиться от зависимости визуалки MSVCP140D.dll

Comment: хотя нет тут что то другое

Comment: 1>glfw3.lib(context.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный в с "__imp____stdio_common_vsscanf"
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный в с  "__imp__strncpy"
1>glfw3.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__strncpy"
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__strncpy"
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный  "__imp__strspn"
1>SOIL.lib(stb_image_aug.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный   "__imp__feof"
1>MSVCRT.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный  "__except_handler4_common"

Comment: Нужна библиотека OpenGL со статической ликновкой.

Comment: что ето значит. Стандартная линковка?