# Как правильно настроить компиляцию в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Я создал программу на с++ windows forms в visual studio 2019, скинул всю программку на другую машину в которой отсутствует visual studio, и при запуске exe файла, выдало что у меня нет VCRUNTIME140D.dll
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как правильно надо настроить visual studio, чтобы можно было открыть exe файл на любой машине. (пробовал сделать как указано в вопросе [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641388/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-exe-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5))